# Working with dialog alert in android

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to create a dialogAlert to check if the user wants to delete a workout but I can't figure out where everything should go in relation to my `onclicklistner`. I have tried moving onclicklistener around but don't know where it should be

Here is my  AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity class:

```
public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lv;
private DBAdapter dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workouts);

    dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();



    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);



    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this workout?.");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }


            });

    builder1.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();


    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                    "You have deleted a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + pos);

            dbHelper.deleteRow(id);
            displayListView();
            return true;

        }

    });


}

private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllRecords();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_WORKOUTDATE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES,

    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.title,
            R.id.workoutDate,
            R.id.workoutDetails,

    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.workout_info,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                          finish();// write this in your code
                    dialog.cancel();
                }


            });                                                                           hope it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm still not sure where my onClickListener should go in all of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 try this,

 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
            getUserConfirmation(id);
            return true;

        }

    });

public void getUserConfirmation(long idSelected){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this);
    builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this workout?.");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);

    builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
 Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this,

                    "You have deleted a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                  dbHelper.deleteRow(idSelected);
                  displayListView();
                }


            });

    builder1.setNegativeButton(
            "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
    alert11.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but this made my app crash? do you know why?

Comment: this is the error android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110828/discussion-between-user3091082-and-srinivasan).

Answer (score 0):

You are canceling dialog when user press yes, instead put logic to delete item here.

```
 builder1.setPositiveButton(
            "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   //dialog.cancel();
                   //write logic to delete item here.
                   dbHelper.deleteRow(id);
                   displayListView();                  
                   dialog.dismiss();

                }


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and if you have any problem let me know

```
 listview.onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
        alert.setTitle("Delete");
        alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete");
        alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

            "You have deleted a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.v("long clicked", "pos: " + pos);

            dbHelper.deleteRow(id);
            displayListView();                  
            dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
        return true;
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long id) {
        //this is where you want the user to confirm, so you show the dialog
         showDeleteConfirmationDialog(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this, id);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The dialog code is moved to a helper function ...

```
private static void showDeleteConfirmationDialog(Context context, long id){
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Delete Workout")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this workout?.")
        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"You have deleted a workout!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dbHelper.deleteRow(id);
            displayListView();                  
            dialog.dismiss();   
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // do not delete, ; 
                dialog.dismiss(); 
            }
        }).show();
}
```